# Full crawl in Sharepoint Foundation 2010

Tags: search, sharepoint-foundation

How we do a full crawl in Sharepoint Foundation 2010?

Comment: I followed your steps and get Failed - "Requested registry access is not allowed." after I checked on the job history status. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checklist inside Central Administration:

- Services on Server -> SharePoint Foundation Search is started.
- Manage Web Applications -> Highlight SharePoint 80 -> User Policy -> Set crawl account to full read.
- Manage Content Content Datases -> WSS_Content -> Search Server -> Select the Search Server for Foundation 2010
- Monitoring -> Job Definitions -> SharePoint Foundation Search Refresh -> Run Now

This does your index reset and full crawl.

Comment: Does this index the content of the site? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/76412/11609

Answer (score 1):

Or via Powershell

GEt all data about your Search Service via

```
Get-SPSearchService | select *
```

after this you shall find something like JobDefinition : {NAME}

or go for

```
(Get-SPSearchService).jobdefinitions | select *
```

which shall give you all details about TimerJobs associated with Search. and simple use

```
Set-SPTimerJob "<NAME>"
   -Schedule "daily between 01:00:00 and 04:00:00"
```