# What's the difference between foundation search and foundation help search?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search

I have a SP foundation farm with SharePoint Foundation help search running, which does not work. I installed SharePoint Foundation help search on my local machine and got the search working out the box.

What's the difference? How to I setup my test environment to mimic my companies production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Help search is the service that index *help content*, whereas foundation search is the service application that index *content*. In SharePoint 2010 *SharePoint Foundation Search Service* is the help search and *SharePoint Server Search* is the content search.

To make both environments work the same you need to setup both the service (on the server) and the service application (in Central Administration or by using PowerShell).